# cakePhp save manyToMany entity

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to save an entity A associated with an entity B without success so far.

The reason is when I tried to save the entity A with the association(entity B) in my relationship Table the id of entity B is set but not the id of entity A.

And the same is the other way.

Here my code for the two entities :

Entity A

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('user_id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsToMany('Shelves', [
        'className' => 'Shelves',
        'foreignKey' => 'shelf_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'shelf_id',
        'joinTable' => 'shelvesSalesmen',
        'through' => 'ShelvesSalesmen'
    ]);
}
}
```

Entity B

```
class ShelvesTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('shelves');
    $this->displayField('shelf_id');
    $this->primaryKey('shelf_id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsToMany('Salesmen', [
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinTable' => 'shelves_salesmen',
        'through' => 'ShelvesSalesmen'
    ]);
}
}
```

RelationShip table

```
class ShelvesSalesmenTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('shelves_salesmen');
    $this->displayField('shelf_id');
    $this->primaryKey(['shelf_id', 'user_id']);
    $this->belongsTo('Shelves');
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
}
}
```

and for the saving is the same code in edit and add action :

```
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
$this->Users->save($user);
```

The error is:

Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (1, ), expecting (shelf_id, user_id)

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Could you post the code that is saving?

Comment: I posted the saving code.

Comment: I tried to start all over again and I it's working.